# Possible to set default slicer value in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerpivot, dax

We have a Power Pivot report that displays some financial information given a current date range. While I can write some SQL or DAX to limit the entire dataset to that date range, I'd rather the workbook contain a large window of transactions -- but default a slicer to the current date.

Is it possible to dynamically set a slicer's value in PowerPivot? Maybe by passing parameters? I'd rather not use Visual Basic, as we'd like this to run in Excel Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is yes.

You can utilize a flag on the date table that flags the current date and default a slicer value to TRUE/YES.

Another option is this pretty nifty idea here:  http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Setting-the-Default-Value-of-a-Slicer/m-p/16449#M4552